# Does Blade of Blood accept temporary hit points?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, temporary-hit-points

If my duskblade has temporary hit points and causes himself 5 hit points of damage using the Blade of Blood spell, would the damage come off the temporary hit points, or his regular hit points?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Essentially, [temporary hit points](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/injuryandDeath.htm) are typically lost first, before a creature's normal hit points are lost (*Player's Handbook* 146, *Rules Compendium* 72). It usually doesn't matter *how* the creature loses the hit points as long as the hit points are lost due to hit point damage. (For example, a creature that suffers from Constitution ability score damage might *seem* to lose hit points when, in fact, the creature's *maximum* hit points have been reduced, so its temporary hit points are unaffected.)

The 1st-level duskblade spell *blade of blood* [necro] (*Player's Handbook II* 103) specifically allows the caster to deal himself hit point damage; this damage is typically subtracted first from the caster's temporary hit points, if any.